# FullCalendar Get Events (as a function) using a Promise not waiting before rendering

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to call an async function to get the events as a function using a promise and this code is "working" as expected (I get the events in the console.log), only that FullCalendar is not waiting for the successCallback, it is simply displaying an empty calendar.

```
  events: function(fetchInfo,successCallback){
    getAllEvents({StartDate:fetchInfo.start,EndDate:fetchInfo.end})
    .then((returnEvents) => {
      console.log(returnEvents);
      successCallback(returnEvents);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })


  } ,
```

Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it was working correctly, just didn't have the return events set as an Array.